# UIAlertView and cocos2d memory mangement

Tags: iphone, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I display a UIAlertView above my cocos2d layer.

I release it after I how it.

Is it really gone?  Do I have to somehow remove it from my UIView?

Comment: can you post the code where you create and display it, as well ast the code where you release it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just do

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

then there's no need to worry about it. However, if you set the alert's delegate to some object, make sure that object still exists when the user taps a button in the alert - otherwise your app will crash when the alert will try to call alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: delegate method.